# KendoUi schedulardata not display in schedular

Tags: kendo-ui

I am not able to display data in schedular of kendoUI->read function using remote binding.
Is there any special way for read data from kendoUI schedualr Or AM i missing something please guide me proper.

Data reading via ajax is display in firebug but not display in schedular
ajax is working but there is some break in code i dont know please help me to out from this

```
    $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
   date: new Date("2014/6/01"),
   startTime: new Date("2014/6/01 07:00 AM"),
   height: 600,
   views: [
       "day",
       "week",
       "month",
       { type: "workWeek", selected: true },

   ],
   timezone: "Etc/UTC",

transport: {
         read: {
              url: "http://abc/abcxyz/abc/read",
              dataType: "json"
        },
        update: {
            url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/update",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        },
        create: {
             url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/create",
             dataType: "jsonp"
        },
        destroy: {
        }
    },
    schema: {
           model: {
          id: "id",
          fields: {
                   id:{ type: "number", from: "business_id"},
                   from: { type: "date", from: "from" },
                   to: { type: "date", from: "to" },
                   id:{ type: "number", from: "id"},
                   name:{ type: "string", from: "name"}

                }
         }
      }
}); 
});
```

Please help me out for above issue,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you try the with the kendoUi Schedular demo ? Please try this one
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index